# Python: My code is not printing out the count of vowels

Tags: python

```
 def is_vowel (character):

   
    if (character == 'a'or character == 'o' or character == 'u' or character == 'i' or character == 'e'):
    
        return True
    else:
        return False

def count_vowels_iter(string, sentence):
    count = 0

    for character in sentence:
       if (is_vowel(character) == True):
        count==count+1
        return count
count = count_vowels_iter('sentence')
print (count)
```

Can someone please help me I am a newbie.  There must be something that I am not finding.

Comment: Look  where your `return` statement is in `count_vowels_iter`.

Comment: Also think of what `count == count + 1` does.

Comment: you need to unindent `return count` and replace `count == count + 1` with `count = count + 1`

Comment: `count==count+1`? use single`=` for assignment. `count=count+1` or `count += 1`

Comment: As an aside, you can use `filter` here. Something like this `len(list(filter(is_vowel, "abcdef")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `count_vowels_iter`, takes 2 arguments (`string` and `sentence`) and when calling the function you only provide 1.

Secondly. your `return` statement needs to be after the `for` loop has been completed as follows:

```
def count_vowels_iter(string, sentence):
    count = 0

    for character in sentence:
       if (is_vowel(character) == True):
        count=count+1
    return count
```

`count==count+1` should be `count=count+1` as your are assigning `count` a new value, not comparing it.

Comment: I only want it to call sentence so can I get rid of string

Comment: @supercarlover Yes, in that case, it would be: `def count_vowels_iter(sentence):`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here. `count_vowels_iter` is accepting two parameters: `string` and `sentence`, but you are only passing in one. The next issue is the way you are incrementing `count`. There should only be one `=` sign. The last issue is the location of your `return` statement. You are returning the count once for every character in `sentence`. You should remove the indentation so that it only returns once after all characters have been checked.